# Free the memory after it is allocated with calloc() to create an array of strings

Tags: c

After allocating memory with `calloc()` to create an array of strings, I want to try to free it and make sure that both strings and string pointers are permanently deleted.

The code is as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **arr;
    arr = calloc(3, sizeof(char *));
    arr[0] = calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    arr[1] = calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    arr[2] = calloc(30, sizeof(char));

    arr[0] = "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds";
    arr[1] = "oru95u9iojituy";
    arr[2] = "hggpooki0opkopreiyh";

    free(arr[2]); free(arr[1]); free(arr[0]);
    //free(arr[0]); free(arr[1]); free(arr[2]);
    free(arr);
}
```

As you can see in the end I tried to free up the memory allocated for strings. In the commented line I tried to free the memory in the opposite direction, believing that I had to follow the order in which the strings appeared in the array.
Despite this, I always get the following error:

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

I can't understand the problem. I know that each `calloc ()` / `malloc ()` must have its respective `free ()`. It seems to be no memory address in arr [i], even though I called a calloc to it.
How can I go about freeing up the memory completely?

Comment: You're not freeing the memory that you allocated, you're trying to free the memory of the string literals.

Comment: You could use `arr[0] = strdup("jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds");` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr[0] = "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds";
arr[1] = "oru95u9iojituy";
arr[2] = "hggpooki0opkopreiyh";
```

This isn't actually filling memory with string data, it's re-assigning and overwriting the pointers you just created with the `calloc()` call. String literals in C are themselves treated as pointers. If you want to initialize your pointers with the string data, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(arr[0], "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds");
strcpy(arr[1], "oru95u9iojituy");
strcpy(arr[2], "hggpooki0opkopreiyh");
```

Comment: Ok, now everything works correctly. I understood the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an error because the array elements no longer point to the memory that you allocated. The assignment

```
arr[0] = "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds";
```

makes it point to the string literal instead.

You should use

```
strcpy(arr[0], "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds");
```

to copy the literal string into the allocated memory (and similar for the other elements).

Comment: Ok, now everything works correctly. I understood the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the expression `arr[0] = "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds";` takes the address of the array of characters "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds" and assigns it to the pointer stored in `arr[0]`. That overwrites the address of the buffer you allocated.

What you want to do is copy those letters into the memory pointed to by `arr[0]`, i.e. the buffer that you allocated.

`strcpy_s( arr[0], 30, "jhgfdjhgfdjhgfds" );`

Note that you should really store that value 30 in a constant rather than repeating it throughout your code.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks, now I understand.